# Find broken sequence with match_recognize using Oracle 12C

Tags: database, oracle

I want to detect gaps in my CDR_ID sequence for each numbers, for that I am using the match_recognize analytic function.

Code:

```
SQL> select  distinct number,
             cdr_id,
             status_sequence
      from    TMP_CDR_GAPS  match_recognize (
                        partition by number 
                        order     by cdr_id
                        measures  match_number() status_sequence
                        all rows per match
                        after match skip past last row
                        pattern   (section_start in_seq_value*)
                        define    in_seq_value as (cdr_id = prev(cdr_id))
                        )
```

This is the result I get :

```
NUMBER          CDR_ID      STATUS_SEQUENCE                         
003301011849    536         1
003301011849    537         2
003301011849    538         3
003301011849    539         4
003301011849    540         5
003301011849    541         6
003301011849    542         7
003301011849    544         8           <-- !!! 
003301011849    545         9
003301011849    546         10
003301011849    547         11
003301011849    548         12
```

**You will notice that CDR_ID 543 is missing**, this is exactly what I want to detect, so I am expecting the STATUS_SEQUENCE to restart to 1 for the next CDR_ID (CDR_ID 544 in this case).

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong with the match_recognize syntax ?

Thank you upfront, 
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With stacking a few analytics over each other...

```
with detect_first_in_seq$ as (
    select X.*,
        case when lnnvl(lag(X.cdr_id) over (partition by num order by cdr_id) = X.cdr_id-1) then X.cdr_id end as is_first_cdr_id_in_seq
    from tmp_cdr_gaps X
),
copy_first_in_seq$ as (
    select X.*,
        last_value(is_first_cdr_id_in_seq ignore nulls) over (partition by num order by cdr_id) as first_cdr_id_in_seq
    from detect_first_in_seq$ X
)
select
    X.*,
    row_number() over (partition by num, first_cdr_id_in_seq order by cdr_id) as status_sequence
from copy_first_in_seq$ X
;
```

With a slightly modified query of yours and one additional analytic...

```
select num, cdr_id,
    row_number() over (partition by num, sequence_group order by cdr_id) as status_sequence
from tmp_cdr_gaps
    match_recognize (
        partition by num
        order     by cdr_id
        measures  match_number() sequence_group
        all rows per match
        after match skip past last row
        pattern   (section_start in_seq_value*)
        define    in_seq_value as (cdr_id = prev(cdr_id)+1)
    );
```

And, finally, with the `match_recognize` only...

```
select *
from tmp_cdr_gaps
    match_recognize (
        partition by num
        order by cdr_id
        measures count(1) as status_sequence
        all rows per match
        after match skip past last row
        pattern (sequence_group in_sequence*)
        define in_sequence as (cdr_id = prev(cdr_id)+1)
    );
```

This seems to work because, as I found out [in Oracle doc](http://file:///O:/oracle-12.1.0.2-html/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#BABIDJGB), the aggregate functions in `match_recognize()` have the default modus operandi of doing *running* aggregates.

Thanks, too, for getting me another bit closer to mastering this wonderful addition to SQL. :-)

**As for your *Can someone help me to understand what is wrong with the match_recognize syntax ?* ...**

There are multiple things wrong:

1. Your `in_seq_value` defined as `cdr_id = prev(cdr_id)` does not make sense. With this definition you're saying that you want to identify sequences of the same `cdr_id` values, whereas you in fact want to identify sequences of `cdr_id` values increasing by 1.
2. Your `match_number() status_sequence` numbers sequentially each found pattern. For `cdr_id = prev(cdr_id)` such pattern would match 12 one-row "subgroups", each numbered sequentially. For `cdr_id = prev(cdr_id)+1` that would be `1` for rows with `cdr_id` from `536` to `542` and `2` for rows with `cdr_id` from `544` to `548`.